# How can we sort Firebase Firestore data by TimeStamp dataType using Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

I am having Ticket Posting Web App, and i would show only those tickets which are active and with-in 24 hours records(from now on).

I am using **Firebase Cloud Firestore** with **Angular 7**.

```
 getTicketList(){
 this.ticketData = 
 this.fireStore.collection('ticket').doc("paid").collection("ticket-list", 
 ref =>
 ref.where('status', '==', 
  "active").where("paid","==","false").orderBy("myTimeStamp");
 return this.ticketData.snapshotChanges() ;
 }
```

We are having a a key "myTimestamp" which is **Firestore Timestamp** Type.

want to show only those records which are active and currently having a time remaining to book.

Beow i mentioned the codes which i am using to get from Firebase service.

```
 this.firestore.getTicketList().subscribe(list => {
  this.ticketList = list.map(item => {
    return { id:item.payload.doc.id,
      ...item.payload.doc.data()}
  })
  console.log(this.ticketList);
});
```

Thanks

Edited

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can query on a data/timestamp field by passing a `Date` object. So for example to get all items before right now:

```
ref
  .where('status', '==', "active")
  .where("paid","==","false")
  .where("myTimeStamp","<", new Date())
  .orderBy("myTimeStamp")
```

Comment: Hello Frank, please look at the image which i have added into my questions. we have made these changes, but still getting no results and received an error.

Comment: The query indeed requires an index. If you click the link in that error, it will take you right to the console page to create the necessary index.

Comment: Going to the broken link.....firebase console... I dont have any index in my database.

Comment: You'll need to add an index on `status`, `paid`, and `myTimeStamp`. If the link is broken, you might want to [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen How are you comparing JS Date() format with Firestore timestamp? Moreover, Firestore Timestamp doesn't use any timezone !

Comment: @dontdownvoteme Firestore's timestamp format does use timezone. You can see it on the Firestore console.