# Firebase Order By Timestamp

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on project just for learning purposes and first time using firebase. I have the data stored in the format below. I will like to orderBy the key (timestamp) when I pull the data. How can I do this?
Currently I have the code below that is working but records are not in order.
Thank you!

I'm adding this after the comment below about Data Modelling. I have changed the timestamp to be a numeric value. Some things I should mention.

1. Document Id is the user id
2. The date will never repeat, I need
   to store a set of data for each day.

And by the way I am just saving date with Date.
Appreciate any guidance. Thanks again.

[image]

```
const performanceRef = firestore.doc(`performance/${user.id}`);
const doc = await performanceRef.get();

     if(doc.exists) {
      const docArray = Object.keys(doc.data());
      console.log(docArray);
    }
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time parsing what I'm looking at in the screenshot. Can you expand the screenshot to show a bigger portion of the Firebase console? It might also help to see the code of how you added this data.

Comment: It looks like you're using timestamp strings as map field names.  That's **very** odd.  I would strongly consider coming up with a new way to model your data.

Comment: @DougStevenson i was wondering if someone will provide me input regarding that. I'm not a backend developer. I just needed to serve some data for the app I'm practicing with and decided to use firebase. So is that a big NO if I store the timestamp like that? (updated the image above). I  was thinking may be store the numeric value for timestamp?

Comment: Firestore field names are never numeric.  They are always strings.  But you are free to convert and sort them any way you like in your client code.  Firestore will not do that for you with field names.

Comment: In addition to the other comments, there is a lot of content on Stack about similar cases, of ordering by timestamps. Have you checked any of them to verify if they provide you insights about how to approach this? You can check for example, this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48500547/order-by-a-number-field-where-a-timestamp-is-on-a-given-date-in-cloud-firestore) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54061164/how-can-we-sort-firebase-firestore-data-by-timestamp-datatype-using-angular).

Comment: @DougStevenson oh ok, but you think it is not a good idea to have a timestamp string? Do you have a suggestion how I can group this data better.

Comment: @gso_gabriel Thank you, I'll take a look. So fare I read quite a bit of threads and I just could not get the orderBy to work. I get an error. so not sure what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Hi @sayayin were you able to take a look and did it help you solve your case?